# Entity Framework - Interact with Orace and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, architecture

I am working on a .NET web api service(with Odata support) to support Mobile client.The service should support both Oracle and SQL server databases, but only one database type will be used at a time, according to which ever database technology client is using.

How to create database agnostic data access layer? Dont want to write code twice - once for SQL server and once for Oracle.

Also it seems like in order to support oracle in EF, 3rd party oracle drivers are required - either from devart or oracle's ODP.NET.

I am debating should I use old style ADO.NET or use EF for building data access layer.

I will appreciate any help on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question seems to revolve around multiple concerns, i'll give answers based on my views on them:

1.- ¿How can you create a Database (DB Engine) agnostic DAL?

A: One approach for this is to follow the [Repository](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) pattern and/or use interfaces to decouple the code that manipulates the data from the code that retrieves/inserts it. The actual implementation of the interfaces used by your code to get the data can also be taylored to be DB Engine agnostic, if you're going to use ADO.NET, you can check out the [Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440726(v=pandp.60).aspx) for some very useful code which is DB Engine agnostic. Entity Framework is also compatible with different DB engines but, as you mentioned, can only interact with one DB at a time, so whenever you generate the model, you tie it to the specifics of the DB Engine that your DB is hosted in. This is related to another concern in your question:

2.- ¿Should you use plain old ADO.NET or EF?

A: This is a very good question, which i'm sure has been asked before many times and given that both approaches give you the same practical results of being able to retrieve and manipulate data, the resulting question is: ¿what is your personal preference for coding and the time/resources constraints of the project?

IMO, Entity Framework is best suited for Code-First projects and when your business logic doesn't require complex logging, transactions and other security or performance constraints on the DB side, not because EF is not capable of including these requirements, but because it becomes rather convoluted and unpractical to do it and i personally believe that defeats the purpose of EF, to provide you with a tool that allows for rapid development.

So, if the people involved in the project is not very comfortable writing stored procedures in SQL and the data manipulation will revolve mostly around your service without the need for very complex operations on the DB side, then EF is a suitable approach, and you can leverage the Repository pattern as well as interfaces to implement "DBContext" objects that will allow you to create a DB Agnostic DAL.

However, if you are required to implement transactions, security, extensive logging, and are more comfortable writing SQL stored procedures, Entity Framework will often prove to be a burden for you simply because it is not yet suited for advanced tasks, for example:

- Imagine you have a User table, with multiple fields (Address, phone, etc) that are not always necessary for all user-related operations (such as authentication); Trying to map an entity to the results of a stored procedure that does not return any of the fields that the entity contains will result in an error, and you will either need to create different models with more or less members or return additional columns in the SP that you might not need for a particular operation, increasing the bandwith consumption unnecessarily.
- Another situation is taking advantage of features such as Table Valued Parameters in SQL Server to optimize sending multiple records at once to the DB, in this case Entity Framework does not include anything that will automatically optimize operations with multiple records, so in order to use TVPs you will need to manually define that operation, much like you would if you had gone the ADO.NET route.

Eventually, you will have to weigh the considerations of your project against what your alternatives provide you; ADO.NET gives you the best performance and customization for your DB operations, it is highly scalable and allows optimizations but it takes more time to code, while EF is very straightforward and practical for objects manipulation, and though it is constantly evolving and improving, its performance and capabilities are not quite on pair with ADO.NET yet.

And regarding the drivers issue, it shouldn't weigh too much in the matter since even Oracle encourages you to use their driver instead of the default one provided by Microsoft.

Comment: Excellent thorough answer. Thanks!